# Power BI dashboards - displaying filtered data on a button click

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I am trying to build a dashboard where there are three tables - Class, Subject, School. Is it possible to display details of the subjects on the click of a class and if we select one of the subjects it should reflect schools that are related to subjects like one shown in the image?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

All the visuals you want to have live interaction should be from a single report, and then you can [pin that whole report to a dashboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/service-dashboard-pin-live-tile-from-report).

Or just use a report page instead of creating a dashboard at all.